# What does these missing country_criteria_id represent for GoogleAdsAPI？

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm working to get cost grouped by country of  my account with `Google ads API`. But I got some `country_criteria_id` that I couldn't found in [Geo Target CSV file](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/geotargeting#columns). And after googled this I found these country may be meet [Google Ads country restrictions policy](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6163740), but I couldn't find the relationship between the ids and countries.

```
2192
2736
2760
2408
```

Can you tell me the relationship?

Comment: https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6163740?hl=en  but don't have 2736

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google don't have the criterion Id - location name mapping documented for those locations that cannot be targeted using AdWords.](https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/BQSKSgNiOMg)

The criterion id `"2364"` is associated with `Iran`.

But there's no map with other country_id meeted restrictions policy.

```
2192
2736
2760
2408
```